# App crashes in review but not locally - How can I find the source from the crashlog?

Tags: macos, debugging, xcode5, crash-reports

I have submitted a new version of my app for review and it was rejected because the app crashed. I got a screenshot showing the button that was clicked before the crash and the crashlog. However I was not able to reproducte the problem and have no idea what the source could be.

The button triggers a disconnection from iCloud which actually just releases some resources. Nothing that should make any trouble. I tried to interpret the crashlog but had no success. I studied several resources from the web but was not able to find any clue what might be the source of the problem.

I managed to symbolicate the crashlog. However this does not change a lot since only the two first entries in the crashed thread belong to my own code. The Exception Codes are not helpfull to me either.

Can anyone see more details from the log or give me a hint were to start with my search? Thank you very much!

```
Process: MyApp [69811]
Path: /Applications/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp
Identifier: com.example.MyApp
Version: 1.2 (1.2)
App Item ID: 0
App External ID: 0
Code Type: X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process: launchd [184]
Responsible: MyApp [69811]
User ID: 201

Date/Time: 2014-01-29 13:20:22.910 -0800
OS Version: Mac OS X 10.9.1 (13B42)
Report Version: 11
Anonymous UUID: FE66701D-3E78-131A-A6CA-844122FA6616

Sleep/Wake UUID: DF88CF2B-42D1-40BD-BAC7-4C433EC11A34

Crashed Thread: 0 Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type: EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x00007fff9266ea52 __semwait_signal_nocancel + 10
1 libsystem_c.dylib 0x00007fff8ca39a7c nanosleep$NOCANCEL + 189
2 libsystem_c.dylib 0x00007fff8ca635fe usleep$NOCANCEL + 54
3 libsystem_c.dylib 0x00007fff8ca8fbc4 abort + 135
4 coop.plausible.CrashReporter 0x000000010343030e uncaught_exception_handler + 27
5 com.apple.CoreFoundation 0x00007fff8bc0f8c2 __handleUncaughtException + 706
6 libobjc.A.dylib 0x00007fff8a805304 _objc_terminate() + 94
7 libc++abi.dylib 0x00007fff8e6623e1 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 8
8 libc++abi.dylib 0x00007fff8e662456 std::terminate() + 54
9 libobjc.A.dylib 0x00007fff8a8050b0 objc_terminate + 9
10 libdispatch.dylib 0x00007fff91e912c1 _dispatch_client_callout + 28
11 libdispatch.dylib 0x00007fff91e98f03 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 333
12 com.apple.CoreFoundation 0x00007fff8bb76839 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
13 com.apple.CoreFoundation 0x00007fff8bb31b14 __CFRunLoopRun + 1636
14 com.apple.CoreFoundation 0x00007fff8bb31275 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309
15 com.apple.HIToolbox 0x00007fff93622f0d RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 226
16 com.apple.HIToolbox 0x00007fff93622cb7 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 479
17 com.apple.HIToolbox 0x00007fff93622abc _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 65
18 com.apple.AppKit 0x00007fff875e928e _DPSNextEvent + 1434
19 com.apple.AppKit 0x00007fff875e88db -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 122
20 com.apple.AppKit 0x00007fff875dc9cc -[NSApplication run] + 553
21 com.apple.AppKit 0x00007fff875c7803 NSApplicationMain + 940
22 com.example.MyApp 0x0000000102f92242 main (receipt.h:4115)
23 com.example.MyApp 0x0000000102f8adb4 start + 52


Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x00007fff9266f662 kevent64 + 10
1 libdispatch.dylib 0x00007fff91e9343d _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 239
2 libdispatch.dylib 0x00007fff91e93152 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 52

Thread 2:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.coredata.ubiquity.entry.pq
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x00007fff9266aa56 semaphore_wait_trap + 10
1 libdispatch.dylib 0x00007fff91e95a15 _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 206
2 com.apple.CoreServicesInternal 0x00007fff931587a0 Dispatch_to_LBGetAttributeValueForItem(__CFURL const*, __CFString const*, void const**, __CFError**) + 450
3 com.apple.CoreServicesInternal 0x00007fff931588e8 ExternalProviderPrepareValues(__CFURL const*, __FileCache*, __CFString const* const*, void const**, long, void const*, __CFError**) + 97
4 com.apple.CoreServicesInternal 0x00007fff9314517f prepareValuesForBitmap(__CFURL const*, __FileCache*, _FilePropertyBitmap*, __CFError**) + 227
5 com.apple.CoreServicesInternal 0x00007fff93142e6b _FSURLCopyResourcePropertyForKeyInternal(__CFURL const*, __CFString const*, void*, void*, __CFError**, unsigned char) + 213
6 com.apple.CoreServicesInternal 0x00007fff93142d91 _FSURLCopyResourcePropertyForKey + 15
7 com.apple.CoreFoundation 0x00007fff8bb1d6bb CFURLCopyResourcePropertyForKey + 123
8 com.apple.CoreFoundation 0x00007fff8bb247e8 -[NSURL getResourceValue:forKey:error:] + 72
9 com.apple.CoreData 0x00007fff8e8a5cab -[PFUbiquityLocationStatus getBoolResourceFromURL:forKey:] + 59
10 com.apple.CoreData 0x00007fff8e8a5989 -[PFUbiquityLocationStatus checkFileURLState] + 217
11 com.apple.CoreData 0x00007fff8e96141d -[PFUbiquityFilePresenter processPendingURLs] + 1453
12 libdispatch.dylib 0x00007fff91e941d7 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
13 libdispatch.dylib 0x00007fff91e912ad _dispatch_client_callout + 8
14 libdispatch.dylib 0x00007fff91e9368f _dispatch_queue_drain + 451
15 libdispatch.dylib 0x00007fff91e949dd _dispatch_queue_invoke + 110
16 libdispatch.dylib 0x00007fff91e92fa3 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 75
17 libdispatch.dylib 0x00007fff91e94193 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 40
18 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x00007fff8d170ef8 _pthread_wqthread + 314
19 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x00007fff8d173fb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 3:
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x00007fff9266ee6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x00007fff8d170f08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x00007fff8d173fb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 4:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-priority
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x00007fff9266dfe2 __fcntl + 10
1 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x00007fff9266ca4d fcntl + 240
2 libsqlite3.dylib 0x00007fff88c3885d unixSync + 45
3 libsqlite3.dylib 0x00007fff88c4c4f6 sqlite3WalCheckpoint + 1990
4 libsqlite3.dylib 0x00007fff88c3e926 sqlite3WalClose + 134
5 libsqlite3.dylib 0x00007fff88c3e701 sqlite3PagerClose + 49
6 libsqlite3.dylib 0x00007fff88c3e19c sqlite3BtreeClose + 316
7 libsqlite3.dylib 0x00007fff88c4a673 sqlite3_close + 771
8 com.apple.CoreData 0x00007fff8e868de4 -[NSSQLiteConnection disconnect] + 164
9 com.apple.CoreData 0x00007fff8e868cb2 -[NSSQLCore _disconnect] + 34
10 com.apple.CoreData 0x00007fff8e868a54 -[NSSQLCore willRemoveFromPersistentStoreCoordinator:] + 132
11 com.apple.CoreData 0x00007fff8e887d21 -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator dealloc] + 1041
12 com.apple.CoreData 0x00007fff8e9cfb3e -[PFUbiquityMetadataFactoryEntry dealloc] + 158
13 com.apple.CoreFoundation 0x00007fff8bada86f CFRelease + 591
14 com.apple.CoreData 0x00007fff8e9c9634 -[PFUbiquityMetadataFactory removeCachedCoordinatorsForLocalPeerID:storeName:andUbiquityRootLocation:] + 164
15 com.apple.CoreData 0x00007fff8e96c921 __56-[PFUbiquitySwitchboardEntry unregisterPersistentStore:]_block_invoke + 129
16 libdispatch.dylib 0x00007fff91e941d7 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
17 libdispatch.dylib 0x00007fff91e912ad _dispatch_client_callout + 8
18 libdispatch.dylib 0x00007fff91e9309e _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 326
19 libdispatch.dylib 0x00007fff91e94193 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 40
20 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x00007fff8d170ef8 _pthread_wqthread + 314
21 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x00007fff8d173fb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 5:
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x00007fff9266ee6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x00007fff8d170f08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x00007fff8d173fb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 6:
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x00007fff9266aa1a mach_msg_trap + 10
1 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x00007fff92669d18 mach_msg + 64
2 libclh.dylib 0x00007fff8ffb4dd9 0x7fff8f9a5000 + 6356441
3 libclh.dylib 0x00007fff8fa6ad62 0x7fff8f9a5000 + 810338
4 libclh.dylib 0x00007fff8ffb5c29 0x7fff8f9a5000 + 6360105
5 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x00007fff8d16f899 _pthread_body + 138
6 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x00007fff8d16f72a _pthread_start + 137
7 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x00007fff8d173fc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 7:
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x00007fff9266aa1a mach_msg_trap + 10
1 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x00007fff92669d18 mach_msg + 64
2 libclh.dylib 0x00007fff8ffb4dd9 0x7fff8f9a5000 + 6356441
3 libclh.dylib 0x00007fff8fa6ad62 0x7fff8f9a5000 + 810338
4 libclh.dylib 0x00007fff8ffb5c29 0x7fff8f9a5000 + 6360105
5 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x00007fff8d16f899 _pthread_body + 138
6 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x00007fff8d16f72a _pthread_start + 137
7 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x00007fff8d173fc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 8:
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x00007fff9266ee6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x00007fff8d170f08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x00007fff8d173fb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 9:
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x00007fff9266ee6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x00007fff8d170f08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x00007fff8d173fb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 10:
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x00007fff9266aa1a mach_msg_trap + 10
1 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x00007fff92669d18 mach_msg + 64
2 com.apple.CoreFoundation 0x00007fff8bb32315 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 181
3 com.apple.CoreFoundation 0x00007fff8bb31939 __CFRunLoopRun + 1161
4 com.apple.CoreFoundation 0x00007fff8bb31275 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309
5 com.apple.AppKit 0x00007fff877891ce _NSEventThread + 144
6 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x00007fff8d16f899 _pthread_body + 138
7 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x00007fff8d16f72a _pthread_start + 137
8 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x00007fff8d173fc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 11:
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x00007fff9266ea3a __semwait_signal + 10
1 libsystem_c.dylib 0x00007fff8caaee60 nanosleep + 200
2 libsystem_c.dylib 0x00007fff8caaed52 usleep + 54
3 com.example.MyApp 0x0000000103094935 0x102f89000 + 1095989
4 com.apple.Foundation 0x00007fff8ac0f70b __NSThread__main__ + 1318
5 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x00007fff8d16f899 _pthread_body + 138
6 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x00007fff8d16f72a _pthread_start + 137
7 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x00007fff8d173fc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
rax: 0x000000000000003c rbx: 0x0000000000000000 rcx: 0x00007fff5cc73cc8 rdx: 0x0000000000000001
rdi: 0x0000000000000b03 rsi: 0x0000000000000000 rbp: 0x00007fff5cc73d00 rsp: 0x00007fff5cc73cc8
r8: 0x0000000000000000 r9: 0x0000000000989680 r10: 0x0000000000000001 r11: 0x0000000000000246
r12: 0x00007fff77a019d0 r13: 0x0000610000249c60 r14: 0x0000000000000000 r15: 0x00007fff5cc73d10
rip: 0x00007fff9266ea52 rfl: 0x0000000000000247 cr2: 0x000000010b7ea000

Logical CPU: 0
Error Code: 0x02000170
Trap Number: 133


Binary Images:
0x102f89000 - 0x10323bfc7 +com.example.MyApp (1.2 - 1.2) <B83E276E-EE1B-34FC-A2F3-2A2B83B5C9FB> /Applications/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp
0x1032cb000 - 0x1032dbfff com.apple.StoreKit (1.0 - 232.2) <4A239D2B-4D42-399B-B4F5-EA24297F0E0A> /System/Library/Frameworks/StoreKit.framework/Versions/A/StoreKit
0x1032f0000 - 0x103311fff +com.dropbox.DropboxOSX (1.0 - 1) <E049D51A-3D0F-39BF-A6B9-5AE5C2012C4B> /Applications/MyApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/DropboxOSX.framework/Versions/A/DropboxOSX
0x103330000 - 0x10333dfff +net.hockeyapp.sdk.mac (1.0.3 - 13) <EDD42403-6A15-37BD-B07A-0C6A29955477> /Applications/MyApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/HockeySDK.framework/Versions/A/HockeySDK
0x103351000 - 0x1033d3fff +org.coreplot.CorePlot (1.0) <DD903A7E-06AB-39BD-82E2-BB0FD05039F1> /Applications/MyApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/CorePlot.framework/Versions/A/CorePlot
0x10342c000 - 0x103444fff +coop.plausible.CrashReporter (1.2-beta2) <F09BAC64-DB6C-3692-9089-0A631F40D8B6> /Applications/MyApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/HockeySDK.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CrashReporter.framework/Versions/A/CrashReporter
0x1098b3000 - 0x1098b3fff +cl_kernels (???) <EEF0C5B5-FBEF-4C91-A93B-63B238713561> cl_kernels
0x109900000 - 0x109901fe4 +cl_kernels (???) <038F9490-12F9-40EF-9EC7-A399B73361D4> cl_kernels
0x10990f000 - 0x109910ff9 +cl_kernels (???) <18DB399D-475A-40A3-871B-1C1F473D917F> cl_kernels
0x109912000 - 0x1099f8fef unorm8_bgra.dylib (2.3.58) <9FF943D1-4EF7-36CA-852D-B61C2E554713> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/ImageFormats/unorm8_bgra.dylib
0x10b468000 - 0x10b468ffd +cl_kernels (???) <AEC6D084-A290-485C-BD7C-8E4F139A79E2> cl_kernels
0x10b6ec000 - 0x10b6effff libspindump.dylib (161) <588EDDE0-B20A-3649-92B7-C2226EB237E8> /usr/lib/libspindump.dylib
0x123440000000 - 0x12344087bff7 com.apple.GeForceGLDriver (8.18.22 - 8.1.8) <CFA88606-8A16-3251-A1AA-4BC5F5D74E1C> /System/Library/Extensions/GeForceGLDriver.bundle/Contents/MacOS/GeForceGLDriver
0x7fff608d3000 - 0x7fff60906817 dyld (239.3) <D1DFCF3F-0B0C-332A-BCC0-87A851B570FF> /usr/lib/dyld
0x7fff86ffb000 - 0x7fff87005fff libcommonCrypto.dylib (60049) <8C4F0CA0-389C-3EDC-B155-E62DD2187E1D> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
0x7fff87006000 - 0x7fff872dafc7 com.apple.vImage (7.0 - 7.0) <D241DBFA-AC49-31E2-893D-EAAC31890C90> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vImage.framework/Versions/A/vImage
0x7fff872db000 - 0x7fff87322fff libFontRegistry.dylib (127) <A77A0480-

...Stripped due to the post size limit...


External Modification Summary:
Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
task_for_pid: 1
thread_create: 0
thread_set_state: 0
Calls made by this process:
task_for_pid: 0
thread_create: 0
thread_set_state: 0
Calls made by all processes on this machine:
task_for_pid: 296574
thread_create: 0
thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=217.9M resident=113.2M(52%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=104.6M(48%)
Writable regions: Total=194.4M written=23.0M(12%) resident=57.7M(30%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=136.7M(70%)

REGION TYPE VIRTUAL
=========== =======
CG backing stores 7840K
CG image 184K
CG raster data 292K
CG shared images 204K
CoreAnimation 4756K
CoreData 4K
CoreData Object IDs 4100K
CoreGraphics 4K
CoreImage 8K
Foundation 4K
IOKit 26.6M
IOKit (reserved) 4K reserved VM address space (unallocated)
Image IO 16K
Kernel Alloc Once 8K
MALLOC 118.7M
MALLOC (admin) 32K
Memory Tag 242 12K
Memory Tag 251 24K
OpenCL 40K
SQLite page cache 1024K
STACK GUARD 56.0M
Stack 13.1M
VM_ALLOCATE 21.5M
__DATA 44.7M
__IMAGE 528K
__LINKEDIT 66.5M
__TEXT 151.4M
__UNICODE 544K
mapped file 54.3M
shared memory 68K
=========== =======
TOTAL 572.1M
TOTAL, minus reserved VM space 572.1M
```